# How to remove the space before the ellipsis in excerpt?

Tags: php, functions, excerpt

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the blank space the appears at the end `the_excerpt();` before the ellipsis. **As seen here:**

[image: Random Blank Space]

It doesn't appear to be a part of the ellipsis as I changed `[...]` to `...` using the following code:

```
function new_excerpt_read_more_sign($content) {
    return str_replace('[&hellip;]', '&hellip;', $content);
}

add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_read_more_sign' );
```

What's causing the blank space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress adds a space when applying the `excerpt_more` filters. Filter the `excerpt_more` to change this correctly.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'theme_name_filter_excerpt_more');

function theme_name_filter_excerpt_more() {
    return '&hellip;';
}
```